# Office 2016 Home - cannot install Outlook

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

I've installed Office 2016 Home and but chose (at that time) not to install Outlook. Now I needed and cannot install it, as I don't get a selection dialog.

I ran the SetupProd_OffScrub.exe program and reinstalled but it just installed everything as it was before, without asking, e.g. no Outlook.

I downloaded the .img file, created a customized xml installation:

```
<Configuration>
    <Add SourcePath="D:\Office\" OfficeClientEdition="64">
        <Product ID="ProPlusRetail">
            <Language ID="en-us" />
        </Product>
    </Add>
</Configuration>
```

but this fails with various errors, such as:

[image]

The .img file is mounted in D:, but setup.exe is ran from another location, not sure if that's an issue.

So I'm asking if there's any way to either reinstall Office 2016 and get the selection dialog or just be able to install individual components on top.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have documents backed up, uninstall Office, restart and then install the complete package and update it.

The Microsoft Article I posted is very complete. Office (since 2013) is a single package so just install all of it.

[Repair / reinstall Office](https://microsoftsupport.cc/error-code-30182-2016-office-error-code-30182-2016/)

> 1 – Repair your Office app error code 30182-2016 will be fixed when
> Office repair tool replaces all the corrupted system files. Follow the
> steps below to run repair tool to fix the error.
>
> Open Control Panel using Start. Click on Programs and select Programs
> and Features. Click on the Office product that you want to repair.
> Click Change. Select Quick Repair and click on Repair. If Quick Repair
> didn’t fix the error code 30182-2016, select Online Repair and click
> on Repair. Note: If Office Repair did not fix the error, remove and
> reinstall the Office Suite to fix the error code 30182-2016.

> 2 – Steps to remove Office In case if the error  persists even after
> running Office repair tool, uninstall Office from your computer.
>
> Open Control Panel using Start Click on Programs and select Programs
> and Features. Select Office Suite and click on Remove. Note: If Office
> uninstallation failed or it didn’t fix the error, a manual
> uninstallation is required to completely remove the Office Suite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was pretty silly, but **Office 2016 Home and Student does not contain Outlook**. It only has Word, Excel, Powerpoint and OneNote.

However, for people looking on how to customize this installation and not get any errors, the following configuration.xml file allows ODT customization:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Add SourcePath="D:\" OfficeClientEdition="32">
        <Product ID="HomeStudentRetail">
            <Language ID="en-us" />
            <Logging Level="Standard" Path="%temp%" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Excel" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="PowerPoint" />
            <ExcludeApp ID="Word">
        </Product>
    </Add>
</Configuration>
```

Note the product id which is **HomeStudentRetail**.

Figured it out by hacking the [old configuration tool](https://officedev.github.io/Office-IT-Pro-Deployment-Scripts/XmlEditor.html) from microsoft, since the new one only shows Office 2019:

[image]